# How can I create a new dataframe in R that combines the first date and last date available for each ID?

Tags: r

For instance, suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
ID<-c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C")
StartDate<-as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2019-02-05", "2016-04-18", "2020-03-03", "2021-12-13", "2014-03-03"), "%Y-%m-%d")
TermDate<-as.Date(c("2018-02-01", NA, "2016-05-18", "2020-04-03", "2021-12-15", "2014-04-03"), "%Y-%m-%d")
df<-data.frame(ID=ID, StartDate=StartDate, TermDate=TermDate)

  ID  StartDate   TermDate
1  A 2018-01-01 2018-02-01
2  A 2019-02-05       <NA>
3  B 2016-04-18 2016-05-18
4  B 2020-03-03 2020-04-03
5  B 2021-12-13 2021-12-15
6  C 2014-03-03 2014-04-03
```

What I'm ultimately trying to get is the following:

```
  ID  StartDate   TermDate
1  A 2018-01-01       <NA>
2  B 2016-04-18 2021-12-15
3  C 2014-03-03 2014-04-03
```

Comment: Try grouping and using `last` on TermDate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are functions `first` and `last` in `dplyr` and `data.table` that could help here.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(StartDate = first(StartDate), 
            TermDate = last(TermDate))

#  ID    StartDate  TermDate  
#* <chr> <date>     <date>    
#1 A     2018-01-01 NA        
#2 B     2016-04-18 2021-12-15
#3 C     2014-03-03 2014-04-03
```

With `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(StartDate = first(StartDate), TermDate = last(TermDate)), ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `min` and `max` instead of `first` and `last` will eliminate the need for sorting the data, if not already

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(StartDate = min(StartDate),
         TermDate = max(TermDate))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ID    StartDate  TermDate  
* <chr> <date>     <date>    
1 A     2018-01-01 NA        
2 B     2016-04-18 2021-12-15
3 C     2014-03-03 2014-04-03
```

See if your df is like this

```
> df
  ID  StartDate   TermDate
1  A 2019-02-05       <NA>
2  A 2018-01-01 2018-02-01
3  B 2016-04-18 2016-05-18
4  B 2020-03-03 2020-04-03
5  B 2021-12-13 2021-12-15
6  C 2014-03-03 2014-04-03

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(StartDate = first(StartDate),
         TermDate = last(TermDate))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ID    StartDate  TermDate  
* <chr> <date>     <date>    
1 A     2019-02-05 2018-02-01
2 B     2016-04-18 2021-12-15
3 C     2014-03-03 2014-04-03
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a useful point with using min and max. However, the NA under TermDate means they're currently employed which should be included. So in this particular case, it may be better to sort first.

Comment: `NA` will work with max and min also.  Moreover, if there is any overlapping anywhere, first and last may cause problems even with arrange.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(StartDate = StartDate[1]), 
            TermDate = TermDate[n()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  as.list(
    setNames(
      data.frame(.SD)[cbind(c(1, .N), c(1, 2))],
      names(.SD)
    )
  ), ID
]
```

gives

```
   ID  StartDate   TermDate
1:  A 2018-01-01       <NA>
2:  B 2016-04-18 2021-12-15
3:  C 2014-03-03 2014-04-03
```